# Undefined in OpenCV/nonfree/features2d when using NDK to build

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

When I was using ndk-build, I always got this error, which strangely points to opencv library code.

This is the error message I got:

```
./obj//armeabi/objs/QRCA/QRCA.o: In function `~SURF`:
/----Path---/../sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:107: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF`
/----Path---/../sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:107: undefined reference to `VTT for cv::SURF`
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/QRCA/QRCA.o: In function `fmatch(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >):`
/----Path---/jni/QRCA.cpp:28: undefined reference to `cv::SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool, bool)`
/----Path---/jni/QRCA.cpp:36: undefined reference to `cv::SURF::SURF()`
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/QRCA/QRCA.o: In function `std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >::_M_range_check(unsigned int) const:`
~/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_vector.h:780: undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF`
~/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_vector.h:780: undefined reference to `VTT for cv::SURF`
```

This is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := QRCA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := QRCA.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := gnustl_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, Google before asking question. Here's answer:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/445/242-android-missing-nonfree-package/

Comment: Thanks for replying. I read that post, and I understood there is no nonfree package in opencv4android. What I was trying to do was writing C++ code using OpenCV native library, which has nonfree package, then using NDK to build for Android. So I cannot do that, can I

Comment: No, you can't. Wait for solution from OpenCV.

Comment: Is there a pre-compiled "libnonfree.so" we could use ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem and found this:
http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android (which after another check, is mentioned in the comments in the link above)

It is a walk-through on how to set it up so that the non-free features will be available for the NDK.

In general, the idea is to copy the header/code from the other distributions and then compile your own libnonfree.so for using these features.

I am having difficulties in my dev environment right now so I am not sure how easy it is but it seems to be updated and a good source for a solution.

(I added this answer so that it's written here on the same page as the question and people will not have to go to the other site and roll through the comments to find it)